# laptop monitor stays off after resume

Tags: suspend, xfce

My laptop system is running Ubuntu 20.04 with Xfce 4.14. When I suspend the laptop by closing the lid and then resuming by opening the lid, the laptop screen does not turn on. If I have an external monitor plugged into the hdmi port then that monitor will turn on, at which point I can enter my password to unlock the screen and then run xfce4-display-settings (by pressing fn+f7) to re-enable my laptop monitor.

I can also run this command to turn on the laptop monitor (once I can open a terminal)

```
xrandr --output eDP-1-1 --pos 0x0 --auto
```

I tried putting this line in a shell script and into /etc/pm/sleep.d, but it didn't seem to work.

```
/etc/pm/sleep.d $ cat 20_fix-screen 
#!/bin/sh

case "$1" in
  resume)
    # Enable laptop output
    export DISPLAY=:0.0
    xrandr --output eDP-1-1 --pos 0x0 --auto
    ;;
esac
```

I started to dig into the code for xfce4-display-settings to see what the underlying cause is, but before I get too far does anyone have any idea what the issue could be?

Comment: Has this always been an issue on your laptop, or is it a new problem that started with an update?

Comment: Its always been an issue. I bought this laptop a few months ago from system76. I wiped the OS it came with and installed xubuntu. I failed to notice if the laptop had any issues with the OS it came with. The laptop has onboard graphics as well as a discrete nvidia card, and the issue occurs regardless of which one is enabled. Currently the nvidia card is enabled.

Comment: To help identify if this is due to hardware or the OS, create a bootable USB using system76's OS. Boot into it, and close and open the lid to see what happens. Granted this is not exactly the same as testing with the original system as delivered, but it may help guide you in finding a solution. Pay attention to any special parameters system76 may have set for `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub`. Also note the kernel version they ship with their OS (`uname -r` and `dpkg -l linux-image*`), since this could be a regression in the kernel you are using with Ubuntu.